# Butterfly effect type of function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFt2B.jpg This is an image that explains what I want to achieve without words. I want to have buttons allow the user to press another set of buttons, that can open another set of buttons and all of them replacing a background image of a div depending on the button you press. I'm really at a loss at how to achieve this, I'm not very good at programming the functions.

Below is code that makes it possible for the user to scroll through 9 pictures three at a time but its not exactly what i want to achieve.

```
    <div id="container">
    <div class="adventure">
        <div class="picture"></div>
        <div class="describingtext">
        <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="choice">
         <div id="choiceABC" class="group active">
             <button id="Image1" class="button">A</button>
             <button id="Image2" class="button">B</button>
             <button id="Image3" class="button">C</button>
          </div>
          <div id="choiceDEF" class="group">
            <button id="Image4" class="button">D</button>
            <button id="Image5" class="button">E</button>
            <button id="Image6" class="button">F</button>
          </div>
          <div id="choiceGHI" class="group">
            <button id="Image7" class="button">G</button>
            <button id="Image8" class="button">H</button>
            <button id="Image9" class="button">I</button>
          </div>
        </div>
         <button id="switch">Next Page</button>
    </div>
</div>

$('.button').click(function() {
 var btn = $(this).attr('id');
 var img = "https://placehold.it/600x338?text=" + btn;
 $('.picture').css('background-image',
'url(' + img + ')'
 );
 });

$('#switch').click(function() {
  var act = $('.group.active');
  var next = act.next();
  act.removeClass('active');
  next.addClass('active');
  if (act.attr('id') == "choiceGHI") {
     $('#choiceABC').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to have buttons open another set of buttons".  Do you mean "click another set of buttons"?  Buttons don't "open".

Comment: Yeah, im sorry for that. What i mean is that i want the buttons to depending on which one was pressed, replace themselves with three others. For example, if looking at that picture i linked, lets say we want to take the left-most path. It would be A, A1, and then A1I. I want each button press to allow clicking on three other buttons and replace the current three ones.